# Sending Excess Baggage and Personal Effects from France to USA

Tags: usa, france, relocation, luggage

I am an Indian citizen and will be moving to the USA on an H1B visa in 2 weeks time. I will be sending excess baggage (personal effects and pre-packaged, dry Indian spices) via [sendmybag.com](https://www.sendmybag.com). Per [an other answer about a related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/10934/2236) on travel.SE, I was planning on filling out a [DECLARATION FOR FREE ENTRY OF UNACCOMPANIED ARTICLES form](http://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/CBP%20Form%203299.pdf).

I am confused about a few things:

- Should this form be affixed outside my baggage or inside?
- Who does Part V of the form (PART V -- CARRIER'S CERTIFICATE AND RELEASE ORDER)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both answers to your questions are your carrier :)

- Carrier's certificate and release order

.. This is something your carrier needs to sign, and it basically says "We made sure that the person who gave us this bag also claims ownership of it. They packed it themselves, etc, etc". Don't fill that out. They're sending it on your behalf, so they are obligated to ask you everything you'd be asked if you were carrying it on yourself. That's where they sign to say "we did that"

- Should this form be affixed outside my baggage or inside?

... Let the carrier handle that. It should be outside, but they'll know what to do with it. Follow whatever instructions they gave you for filling out the form and getting your bag to them.

I don't think you'll have any issues with dried spices. Depending on what you packed, I hope we end up neighbors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As for being your neighbor, I am guessing the overwhelming smell of spices don't bother you ... much. `;)` [I'm headed to the gorgeous Upper Peninsula of michigan]